# Few VS less VS lesser VS fewer

Tags: grammar

What’s the difference between:

1. Less and lesser
2. Fewer and lesser

Take this example for instance:

> She has lesser/less/fewer oranges than me.

In such a case, what should the answer be and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formal English, you should use "few" with countable nouns and "less" with uncountable nouns.  "Oranges" is plural, and so countable:

> She has fewer oranges.

This is one of those "rules" that is taught in school but often broken by native speakers. It is very natural to say:

> She has less oranges than me.

"Lesser" is not used in this way,  It means "lower in rank or importance". It is rather rare. Check examples in a dictionary.